# Creating percentiles against total R

Tags: r, percentile

I'm trying to break out my data into percentiles. First, here's some example data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  employee.first.name = c ('Jim', 'John', 'James', 'Jack', 'Jill', 'Kathy',
                           'Kim', 'Kelly', 'Karl', 'Larry', 'Lemon', 'Lime',
                           'Man', 'Mark', 'Mary', 'Miss', 'Molly',
                           'Matthew', 'Nancy', 'Nelly'),
  week.pay = c(401, 70, 58, 130, 483, 464, 84, 327, 208,
               254, 306, 393, 270, 54, 279, 390, 144,
               97, 125, 403
  )
)
```

I'm able to break `week.pay` into percentiles using the `cut2` function:

```
library(Hmisc)
cut2(df$week.pay, g = 4, levels.mean = FALSE)
```

I would like to separate by percent of total pay into quartiles. For example, in the data above, 25% of the total pay is 1235. Doing some math, I can find that if we look at the sum of week pay in the 1 - 255 range, we approximately get back to the 25% amount.

I would like to know the ranges of pay that equate to each quartile. How can I quickly accomplish this in R?

Sorry for my poor title - can't seem to word what I want properly. Monday morning after a holiday weekend isn't working out too well :).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking about quartiles for the cumulative pay. As you note we need to divide the total pay by four to get the  quartiles. That way we can get the quartiles in terms of pay:

```
sorted.pay <- sort(df$week.pay)
cum.pay <- cumsum(sorted.pay)
brk <- floor(cum.pay/(sum(sorted.pay/4)))
brk <- ifelse(brk > 3, 3, brk)   # Include highest pay in 4th group
sapply(split(sorted.pay, brk), range)
#        0   1   2   3
# [1,]  54 270 390 403    # Min
# [2,] 254 327 401 483    # Max
table(brk)
# brk
#  0  1  2  3 
# 10  4  3  3
```

So 10 people in the lowest quartile get paid between 54 and 254 while the 3 people at the top get paid 403 to 483. The 10 people of the bottom get 1/4 of the total payroll and the top 3 get 1/4 of the total payroll.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is along the lines of

```
cut(
    x = df$week.pay
    , breaks = quantile(
         df$week.pay
         , probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25)
         , names = FALSE
         , type = 7)
    , include.lowest = TRUE
)
```

The `quantile` function with this `probs` argument will compute the quartiles for you. Subsequently `cut` will change your initial data vector according those quartiles.

Pay attention to the `type` argument of for how the quantiles / quartiles are computed.